# n.call is not a function issue when doing a transition

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to generate some text labels and to then transition them onto a D3 graph.

Pseudo code: (1) Generate text labels at coordinates 0,0
             (2) Transition labels to desired [x,y]

When I run the script below, however, I get the following issue in the console log window:

[image]

My code is as follows:

```
svg.selectAll(".groups")
           .data(sampleData)
           .append("text")
           .attr("class", "label")
           .text(function(d){return d.c})
           .attr("dx",0)
           .attr("dy", 0)
           .style("fill-opacity",0)
           .each("end", function(){
                d3.selectAll(".label")
                .transition()
                .duration(2000)
                .style("fill-opacity", 1)
                .attr("dx", function(d) {
                    return x(d.x);
                     })
                .attr("dy", function(d) {
                    return y(d.y);
                     }); 
                })
```

Have you any idea what is going wrong? The two bits of code are running just fine. It's the transition that is giving me the headache.

Comment: What's the version of D3?

Comment: Hello Gerardo. The version is V3. I know that in V4, 'each' has been overhauled with 'on'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need that `each` here. [Each](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Transitions.md#each) adds a listener to a transition, but you have no transition selection when you get to that `each` function:

```
svg.selectAll(".groups")
    .data(sampleData)
    .append("text")
    .attr("class", "label")
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.c
    })
    .attr("dx", 0)
    .attr("dy", 0)
    .style("fill-opacity", 0)
    .each("end", function() {...
    //No 'transition()' before this point
```

(by the way, you also don't have an "enter" selection, since there is no `enter` in the code)

Thus, it can be just this: setting the positions to zero (which you don't need to do, because the positions are zero by default), and changing them in the transition selection. Here is the demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var data = ["foo", "bar", "baz", "foobar", "foobaz", "barbaz"];

svg.selectAll("foo")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d
  })
  .style("fill-opacity", 0)
  .transition()
  .duration(2000)
  .style("fill-opacity", 1)
  .attr("dx", function(){ return Math.random()*280})
  .attr("dy", function(){ return 20 + Math.random()*130});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: Gerardo surely I owe you a couple of beers with the number of times you have helped me..

Comment: The day you come down under to Australia you pay me a pint.